# Eigenvalues and vector

Tags: probability, eigenvalues

I have a transition matrix of

[image]

and calculated eigenvalues of :

[image]

How can I calculate the eigenvector and general probability distribution

Answer (score 1):

Defining e as the vector that contains the eigenvalues, and v as the eigenvector, this should hold: Tv = ev. 
You can write this out and obtain a system of equations which you can solve. 
It results in the following; v1 = v2 and v2 = -v3. So take v1 = 1 and your eigenvector will be: v = (1 1 -1)

By the general probability distribution, do you mean the long run probabilities?

Comment: Yes what would that be ?

Comment: Then you have to solve: pi*T = pi, where pi is the long-run probability vector. Try yourself.